# How can I make my setTimout functions run at the same speed?

Tags: javascript, optimization, time

Preface: I have a [demo of the problem](http://progress.xdumaine.com/progressDemo.html) on my personal site (I hope this is ok. If not, I can try to set it up on jsfiddle). I'm intending this question to be a little fun, while also trying to understand the time functions take in javascript.

I'm incrementing the value of progress bars on a timeout. Ideally (if functions run instantaneously) they should fill at the same speed, but in the real world, they do not. The code is this:

```
function setProgress(bar, myPer) {
bar.progressbar({ value: myPer })
    .children('.ui-progressbar-value')
        .html(myPer.toPrecision(3) + '%')
            .attr('align', 'center');
    myPer++;
    if(myPer == 100) { myPer = 0; }
 }

 function moveProgress(bar, myPer, inc, delay){
    setProgress(bar, myPer);
    if(myPer >= 100) { myPer = 0; }
    setTimeout(function() { moveProgress(bar, myPer+inc, inc, delay); }, delay);
 }

 $(function() { 
   moveProgress($(".progressBar#bar1"), 0, 1, 500);
   moveProgress($(".progressBar#bar2"), 0, 1, 500);
   moveProgress($(".progressBar#bar3"), 0, .1, 50);
   moveProgress($(".progressBar#bar4"), 0, .01, 5);             
 });
```

Naively, one would think should all run (fill the progress bar) at the same speed.

However, in the first two bars, (if we call "setting the progress bar" a single operation) I'm performing one operation every 500 ms for a total of 500 operations to fill the bar; in the third, I'm performing one operation every 50ms for a total of 5,000 operations to fill the bar; in the fourth, I'm performing one operation every 5ms for a total of 50,000 operations to fill the bar.

What part of my code is takes the longest, causes these speed differences, and could be altered in order to make them appear to function in the way that they do (the fourth bar gets smaller increments), but also run at the same speed?

Comment: If I'm looking at this right, your labels are off on the example site.  Isnt' the 4th bar .01 every 5ms?

Comment: note that the delay of a `setTimeout` call maybe clamped to a minimum value; 4ms for html5 browsers (and Chrome) but it depends on the browser. i.e. it may clamp it to a larger value like 10ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest problem with using `setTimeout` for things like this is that your code execution happens between timeouts and is not accounted for in the value sent to `setTimeout`.  If your delay is 5 ms and your code takes 5 ms to execute, you're essentially doubling your time.

Another factor is that once your timeout fires, if another piece of code is already executing, it will have to wait for that to finish, delaying execution.

This is very similar to problems people have when trying to use `setTimeout` for a clock or stopwatch.  The solution is to compare the current time with the time that the program started and calculate the time based on that.  You could do something similar.  Check how long it has been since you started and set the % based on that.

Comment: Ahh so the bar would appear to be incrementing at a regular rate, since the time since it began is increasing, but it's a fresh calculation each time, so it would make up for time lost on queued delays and operations?

Comment: Basically.  You could get slightly out of sync for very short amounts of time but would always go right back the next time a timeout fired.

Comment: I realize this is sort of an experimentation thing, but if this were a real situation, you'd probably just want one timer and you'd update all 4 in the same execution.  Then you would always be in sync.

Answer (score 0):

What causes the speed difference two things: first is the fact that you executing more code to fill the bottom bar (as you allude to in the 2nd to last paragraph). Also, every time you set a timeout, your browser queues it up... the actual delay may be longer than what you specify, depending on how much is in the queue (see [MDN on window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting)).

Answer (score 0):

Love the question, i don't have a very precise answer but here are my 2 cents:

Javascript is a very fast language that deals very well with it's event loop and therefore eats setTimeouts and setIntervals for breakfast.
There are limits though, and they depend on a large number of factors, such as browser and computer speed, quantity of functions you have on the event loop, complexity of the code to execute and timeout values...

In this case, i think it's obvious that if you try to execute one function every 500ms, it is going to behave a lot better than executing it every 50ms, therefore a lot better than every 5ms. If you take into account that you are running them all on top of each other, you can predict that the performance will not be optimal.

You can try this exercise:
take the 500ms one, and run it alone. mark the total time it took to fill the bar (right here you will see that it's going to take a little longer than predicted).
try executing two 500ms timeouts at the same time, and see that the total time just got a bit longer.
If you add the 50ms to it, and then the 5ms one, you will see that you will lose performance everytime...